# Option to user to download excel file in Angular

Tags: excel, angular, download

How to download a excel file from server on button click in Angular 8. I am new to Angular and I read through different posts which said to file-saver library. Do we need to install a library to work out download option or not. Can anyone please share the code and insights.

Comment: What your back-end is returning a url or blob?

Comment: On clicking the download button, an excel file is sent so I believe blob.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for example:

```
const resp = await this.httpClient.get(`{yourendpoint}`, { responseType: 'blob' }).toPromise();
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(resp);
window.open(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your getting blob from you backend then you can do something like this:

```
let a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = URL.createObjectURL(data);
a.download = 'FILE_NAME';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
```

Where 'data' is response from your api.

PS: Don't forget to add header `responseType: 'blob'`